# Generate random unique serials

Tags: php, mysql

I want to build a **token** number generator. In each call, a random and unique 8-digit number should be returned. I am using PHP and MySQL. In MySQL I'll have a table where I will insert the new serial, each time it will be generated.

How can I generate new numbers in each call?

Tokens will be used from end-users to activate software (and will expire, e.g. after 1 week). So, I need tokens to be unique and not sequential. This describes better my needs. Token format will be just numbers, so that it can be easily spelled and typed.

Even if tokens expire, I do not want to generate an already generated token at a later time.

Thank you

Comment: use Mysql auto increment and start with 10,000,000.

Comment: is this valid `11223344`? or all numbers are unique `12345678`?

Comment: @ROYFinley, although that would generate unique id's they could hardly be described as random

Comment: Technically, the phrase "serial number" means a number that increases as a series.  *ie* not random.

Comment: @Crisp Serial numbers should not be random, they should auto increment to allow you to track history, I own a heating and air company. we generate serials every day for unit production. our numbers also include a date code.

Comment: @ROYFinley, I'm aware of the definition of a serial number, I was pointing out that's not what the OP asked for ;)

Comment: "Random", "unique" and "an unknown number of" (implied by the question) in the same sentence does not make sense. In all likelihood you want *unpredictable* and unique.

Comment: I think you are all right. I revised my question based on your comments.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so this code does not put the serial number into a database but it will return a serial number 8 digits long. If you want just numbers change the allowed characters variable to just numbers.

```
<?php

    function generate_serial_number() {

       $Allowed_Charaters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890';
       return substr(str_shuffle($Allowed_Charaters), 0, 8);

    }

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the generator, but this does not fulfills the number-unique requirement. Of course, I can insert it in the db until I get no error (due to the unique definition of the relative column).

Answer (score 0):

I usually use http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php with the **more_entropy** parameter to true.

Comment: That sounds good, but how can we get rid of the alphas in there?

Comment: Strip them. Use preg_replace(). But beware, you can have collisions.